# product flavours to generate signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

we are developing a dating app it has both paid and free version ,now we are planning to upload that app in to  google play store as a beta version , but we got struck while generating signed apk , it has the field **flavour**

```
            what's the use of  **product flavour** , Is  it mandatory to generate signed apk ,
```

CASE -I : if I generate signed apk with out any *product flavour*,can we use it as both free and paid app.

CASE-II : if  it is mandatory can I add product flavour after generating signed apk

how to add product flavour  to our android application project, any suggestion will be greately appreciated.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should have the flavors paid and free.
You can define those in the build.gradle of your application.

```
productFlavors {
    paid {
    }

    free {
    }
}
```

If you do so you can chose a flavor while singing your apk.

Have a look https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Comment: can i upload the app  in google play store with out any product flavours in beta version,   and then add product flavours in main production apk ....

Comment: You can do so as long as your applicationId stays the same and you sign the apk with the same keystore.